# Check whether a Windows certificate is valid by date - using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

My target it to check whether a certificate (I have its exact name, in the example below it is "Dell") in **any** Windows computer is valid.
The way I think I can do it, is by taking the expiration date, and compare it with the current date.

So, first, I want to take the expiration date ("not after" field).
The way I did it:

```
certutil -verifystore Root Dell | findstr/n ^^ | findstr "^[6]:" | for /f "tokens=3-5 delims= " %f in ('more') do @echo %f %g %h
```

Output: `3/8/3020 8:47 PM`

But note this is matching my regional date format. I need it to be generic- in a way it would work for all possible formats

Now, for any Windows computer I have the date.

Next step, is to get the current date with `%date%` variable, and calculate the seconds (?) difference between the two dates. With that result I could know whether the certificate is expired or not.

I can't find how to do so. Any advice?

**Few notes:**

- No PowerShell
- only 1 cmd command
- The result of this 1 command should be the seconds difference of the 2 dates
- **Any other way to verify a certificate is acceptable. The way above is the only 1 I know**

Comment: Why no Powershell? Why just 1 "cmd"? These restrictions makes it very hard...

Comment: To begin with, I'd consider changing it to `For /F "Tokens=2,*" %G In ('certutil -verifystore Root Dell ^| find "NotAfter"') Do @Echo %H`. However unless it can be 100% guaranteed what the returned date and time string's format will be for that specific end user, on that specific computer, at that moment in time, there is no robust way, using cmd only, for you to be able to parse that string into substrings you can use for a date comparison. BTW, [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70529660), just a couple of days ago, may have some comments which explain this better.

Comment: @Compo As it seems, Powershell is a must for this case.